# How i can translate the label "browse files" and "upload files"?

Tags: localisation

I need translate the label "browse files" and "upload files" for a extension which uses default uploader of magento.

In *Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader* i changed the function *_prepareLayout()*

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild(
        'browse_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id'      => $this->_getButtonId('browse'),
                'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Browse Files...'),
                'type'    => 'button',
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.browse()'
            ))
    );

    $this->setChild(
        'upload_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id'      => $this->_getButtonId('upload'),
                'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Upload Files'),
                'type'    => 'button',
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.upload()'
            ))
    );

    $this->setChild(
        'delete_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id'      => '{{id}}-delete',
                'class'   => 'delete',
                'type'    => 'button',
                'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Remove'),
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.removeFile(\'{{fileId}}\')'
            ))
    );

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

to

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild(
        'browse_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id'      => $this->_getButtonId('browse'),
                'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Buscar Archivos'),
                'type'    => 'button',
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.browse()'
            ))
    );

    $this->setChild(
        'upload_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id'      => $this->_getButtonId('upload'),
                'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Subir Archivos'),
                'type'    => 'button',
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.upload()'
            ))
    );

    $this->setChild(
        'delete_button',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->addData(array(
                'id'      => '{{id}}-delete',
                'class'   => 'delete',
                'type'    => 'button',
                'label'   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Remove'),
                'onclick' => $this->getJsObjectName() . '.removeFile(\'{{fileId}}\')'
            ))
    );

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

[image: file upload]

but without results

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you elaborate it more? Why do you need label values?

Comment: do this in front end or admin panel?

Comment: You can get label values using jquery/js I think.

Comment: I changed the Question. I need translate the labels, anything more.

Comment: yes answer for the question of @MeenakshiSundaramR

Comment: easiest way is to use javascript/jquery and change those label values as desired. Othewise you may need to find the file that render those buttons and make an edit there

Comment: Interesting question. I can tell you for sure the buttons added by the piece of code you added here are not used. they are commented in `media/uploader.phtml`

Answer (score 2):

You can't afaik translate the label.

This two buttons are part of the flex uploader. The names of the buttons can be found here: `lib/flex/uploader/uploader.mxml` and can be changed there. We tried this but didn't achieve our goal, because we ware not able to compile the flex uploader.

Good luck! If you make it, please tell me which Flash/Flex version you used and ow you did it!